# Count number of integers in text file in C

Tags: c, file, text, malloc, argv

I made text file called **qsort.txt** and wrote arbitrary many integers in file (In my case 35 integers to be precise). My goal is to count how many integers are in that file, put them into an array defined by `malloc()` and sort them using `qsort()`. After that I want sorted numbers writen into a text file called **sorted.txt**.

This is my code, but obviously doesn't work as expected. Also I want to be more flexible with code so in `FILE *fa = fopen(argv[1], "r+")` is `argv[1]` so I can put any other text file to be sorted. Anyway my problem is that I don't know how to count how many integers are in file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
    if (*(int*)a < *(int*)b)
        return -1;
    else if (*(int*)a > *(int*)b)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    FILE *fa = fopen(argv[1], "r+");
    if (!fa)
        exit(1);
    FILE *fb = fopen("sortirano.txt", "w+");

    long duljina, i;
    long *ptr, *zapis;
    long count = 0;

     while (!feof(fa))
         count++;

     printf("%lu\n", count);

     fseek(fa, 0, SEEK_END);
     duljina = ftell(fa);
     fseek(fa, 0, SEEK_SET);

     ptr = (long *)malloc(sizeof(long));

     while (!feof(fa)) {
         fscanf(fa, "%lu", ptr);
         count++;
     }
     printf("count: %lu\n", count);
     for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
         printf("%lu ", ptr[i]);

    printf("\n");

    free(ptr);

    fclose(fa);
    fclose(fb);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

This is my new code, which is simpler:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
    if (*(long*)a > *(long*)b)
        return 1;
    if (*(long*)a < *(long*)b)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int main() {
    FILE *fa = fopen("qsort.txt", "r"); assert(fa != NULL);
    FILE *fb = fopen("sorted.txt", "w+"); assert(fa != NULL);

    long *ptr;
    long save;
    long count = 0;
    long i;
    long k;

    while ((fscanf(fa, "%ld", &save)) == 1) //number of elements
        prebroji++;

    printf("count: %ld\n", count); //checking how many elements i have, just to make sure it works ok

    ptr = (long *)malloc(count * sizeof(long)); //mallociranje

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        fscanf(fa, "%ld", &ptr[i]);

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) //checking if numbers were saved at malloc array
        printf("%ld ", ptr[i]);

    qsort(ptr, count, sizeof(long), compare);

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) //checking if sorted correctly
        printf("%ld ", ptr[i]);

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        fprintf(fb, "%ld", ptr[i]);

    printf("\n");

    free(ptr);
    fclose(fa);
    fclose(fb);

    return 0;
}
```

But it doesn't work: all I got are zeros printed.

Comment: It doesn't work as expected, you say. What does it do instead? Where does it fail? Do you see any error messages?

Comment: You allocate memory for one single `long` value. You read one value at a time, discarding every value except the last. You don't check if `fscanf` fails. And you go way out of bounds of the single `long` value you have. Not to mention that `count` will be wrong, it's not the number of values in the file. In fact, that loop where you calculate `count` is infinite. Oh, and [`while (!feof(fp))`is almost always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong).

Comment: To add some more problems, you should never use an element of `argv` if you don't check that it actually exists (by checking `argc`). And please try to minimize the number of unused variables and functions, to make the code easier to read and understand and maintain. And now I see that you use `count` for different things. Also the `%lu` format is for *unsigned* long values, you should be using `%ld` for plain signed `long`. Mismatching format specifier and argument type actually leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: seeking to the end to call ftell and seeking back to the start is completely pointless.  You don't care how big the file is.  Just read data until there is no more data to read.  Drop all of the `feof` calls (you are using it wrong anyway) and just do `while( fscanf(...) == 1)`.  Also, don't use `fscanf`, but that's a different conversation.

Comment: Can you assume that the file contains only integers and white space (spaces or newlines) ?

Comment: Yes, there are only integers and white space

Comment: @tux, If the file is `"1\n23\n456\n"`, is that 6 or 3 integers?  If the file contains _integers_ outside the `long` range, what should happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the file only contains integers and whitespace, you can parse it with `fscanf("%ld", ...)` and store the numbers into an array you reallocate on purpose as you read more numbers.

Note these remarks:

- Your comparison function is OK for use with `qsort`.
- There is no need to open the files for update with `+` in the mode string,
- nor is there any need for seeking to the end of file.
- testing for end of file with `while(!feof(fa))` is always wrong. You should instead test for `fscanf()` success and reallocate the array as needed.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int compare(const void *aa, const void *bb) {
    const long int *a = aa;
    const long int *b = bb;
    return (*a > *b) - (*a < *b);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "missing argument\n");
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *fa = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!fa) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    long *ptr = NULL;
    size_t alloc = 0, count = 0;
    long value;

    while (fscanf(fa, "%ld", &value) == 1) {
        if (count == alloc) {
            size_t new_alloc = alloc + alloc / 2 + 32;
            long *new_ptr = realloc(ptr, sizeof(*ptr) * new_alloc);
            if (!new_ptr) {
                fprintf(stderr, "out of memory for %zu entries\n", new_alloc);
                free(ptr);
                fclose(fa);
                return 1;
            }
            ptr = new_ptr;
            alloc = new_alloc;
        }
        ptr[count++] = value;
    }
    fclose(fa);

    printf("count: %zu\n", count);

    qsort(ptr, count, sizeof(*ptr), compare);

    const char *outfile = "sorted.txt";
    FILE *fb = fopen(outfile, "w");
    if (!fb) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", outfile, strerror(errno));
        free(ptr);
        return 1;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        fprintf(fb, "%ld\n", ptr[i]);
    }

    fclose(fb);
    free(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

You new code has multiple problems:

- there is no need to open **sorted.txt** in update mode, just use `"w"`.
- you should `assert(fb)` after opening the second file
- `prebroji` should be `count`
- you should add `assert(ptr)` after you allocate the array
- you must add `rewind(fa);` after you allocate the array to re-read the file from the beginning. This explains why you get all values as `0` because you do not test the return value of `fscanf()` that returns `0` or `EOF` for every try.
- it is less brittle to write `qsort(ptr, count, sizeof(*ptr), compare);` to avoid size inconsistencies if you change the type of the array.
- similarly, writing `ptr = malloc(count * sizeof(*ptr))` is more reliable as it remains consistent should you change the type of `ptr`.
- you should add a separator in `fprintf(fb, "%ld", ptr[i])` to separate the numbers you write into the output file.

Comment: Just one more question. After I determined number of elements, how do I copy them (sorted) into file sorted.txt?

Comment: @tux: look at the code. After loading all the numbers, I call `qsort()` to sort the array, then call `fopen()` to create the output file and use `fprintf` to write all the numbers into it.

Comment: When I run this code i get messages like this: "malloc(): corrupted top size", 
"core dump". Also I have one additional problem - when i want to write elements from file into malloc() array nothing happens. I get all zeroes. This is the piece of code that I'm using to write elements but obviously doesn't work: for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
fprintf(fa, "%ld ", ptr[i]);

Comment: How to propertly save elements into malloc array?

Comment: @tux: you should use `fb` instead of `fa`.  I fixed the `realloc` code, I was using `alloc` instead of `new_alloc` for the size computation. Sorry about that.

Comment: Still doesnt write numbers from file **fa**. Again all zeroes.
code:
```ptr = (long*)malloc(count*sizeof(long));

     for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
         fprintf(fb, "%ld", ptr[i]);
```
Your code is fine

Comment: `alloc + alloc / 2 + 32` interesting growth algorithm.  I like `alloc * 2 + 1` for `0,1,3,7,15, ... SIZE_MAX`.

Comment: @tux: I updated the question text with your new version, and updated my answer with explanations for the remaining problems.